# How to change a variable declare inside a function in javascript

Tags: javascript

i have a function and a local variable declared inside it, i don't want to declare it as global because some functions are also using its default value

```
 function default()
 {
      var val="me";
      //others.....
 }
```

is there a way aside from this using prototyping

```
 function default(value)
 {
     var val=value;
     //others.....
 }
```

something like,

```
 default.prototype.val = "you";
```

re-constracting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. It is not possible to declare a variable inside the function (`var myVar`) and then access it once the function has ended. This is because the variable is created within the function's lexical scope and is undefined outside of it. Here is some more info on how scoping works: https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-scope-in-javascript

As for your proposed solution `default.prototype.val` this does not work because default is a function and does not have properties or a prototype. This is something an object would have.

As others have indicated, you may pass in a variable or use default values, but it seemed your were asking about accessing a variable created inside the function and that is not doable. You need to return the value or pass in a variable which is modified by the function.

Comment: thanks for the links, i see a json object that might helps.

Comment: your link is very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

```js
function name(s) {
 return s || "me"
}

console.log(name())
console.log(name("you"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the default values to the arguments

```
function default(value ="you")
 {
     var val=value;
     //others.....
 }
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters

usage will be something like this

```
default(); // value will be "you"
default("me"); value will be "me"
```

Comment: This is nice and it solves the current issue, but its not capable for a deeper purpose. like 

function default()
{
     var val="me";
  var childfunction= function()
  {
      var something= '';
  }

}

Comment: @bdalina What will be the problem ? I don't see any issue there

Comment: the function look like this function test(value, value2, value3, value4), the answer was to use object function test(value={})     where value {'val1':'asd', 'val2':'asfas',etc..}

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```js
function defaultfun (value="") {
  var val = "me";
  alert("new value:"+value+"\n old value:"+val);
}
defaultfun();
defaultfun("you");
```